# python mypy: sorting a list on nullable key - where items with null fields are removed

Tags: python, mypy

I am on a project using mypy 1.2.0. I am linting the following code:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

from pydantic import BaseModel


class ScheduleItem(BaseModel):
    start_date: Optional[date] = None


items = [
    ScheduleItem(start_date=None),
    ScheduleItem(start_date=date.today()),
    ScheduleItem(start_date=date.today() - timedelta(days=3)),
]


sorted_items = sorted(
    [item for item in items if item.start_date],
    key=lambda item: item.start_date,
)
```

I get the following lint errors:

```
error: Argument "key" to "sorted" has incompatible type "Callable[[ScheduleItem], Optional[date]]"; expected "Callable[[ScheduleItem], Union[SupportsDunderLT[Any], SupportsDunderGT[Any]]]"  [arg-type]

error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[date]", expected "Union[SupportsDunderLT[Any], SupportsDunderGT[Any]]")  [return-value]
```

However, I am passing in a list to `sorted` which enforces the values that are being sorted on are not `None`. How do I communicate this to mypy?

Comment: You can't annotate "X with narrowed type of item t". Your best bet would be to create `StrictScheduleItem(ScheduleItem)` with narrowed `start_date: date` and have a `filter_items(Iterable[ScheduleItem]) -> list[StrictScheduleItem]` function to filter your sequence and feed its return to `sorted`. Though it's probably an overkill for such simple code, just drop a `# type: ignore` comment and go on IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `cast` is for: *statically* asserting a type that will be enforced at runtime.

```
from typing import cast


...


sorted_items = sorted(
    [item for item in items if item.start_date],
    key=lambda item: cast(date, item.start_date)
)
```

The type checker will then infer a type of `Callable[[ScheduleItem], date]]` for the function passed as the `key` argument. At runtime, `cast` does nothing except return its second argument.

Comment: "asserting types that will be enforced at runtime" - **please** rewrite this sentence to be less confusing. `cast` is efectively a no-op at runtime (`lambda _, x: x`), while your answer may be interpreted as "`cast` will check the types at run time".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tuple with sort key yourself:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass  # Just for reproducibility ease, works with BaseModel
class ScheduleItem:
    start_date: date | None = None

items = [
    ScheduleItem(start_date=None),
    ScheduleItem(start_date=date.today()),
    ScheduleItem(start_date=date.today() - timedelta(days=3)),
]

# Short and fast, but not mypy-compatible (reveals tuple[Any, ...])
_, sorted_items = zip(
    *sorted((item.start_date, item) for item in items if item.start_date)
)
print(sorted_items)
reveal_type(sorted_items)  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[Any, ...]"

sorted_items_2 = [
    x[1] for x in sorted((item.start_date, item) for item in items if item.start_date)
]
reveal_type(sorted_items_2)  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.list[__main__.ScheduleItem]"
```

Here `mypy` knows [incorrectly] that you sort tuples by a non-none key.

This question discovered a `mypy` limitation: the code above should not be allowed. For it to be type-safe, you must add `itemgetter(0)` as a sort key. `BaseModel`s and `dataclass`es are not comparable, so the code above will raise a `TypeError` if several items have the same date. The correct implementation would be

```py
from operator import itemgetter

# ...

sorted_items_ok = [
    x[1]
    for x in sorted(
        ((item.start_date, item) for item in items if item.start_date), 
        key=itemgetter(0),
    )
]
```

However, `tuple` defines `__lt__` no matter what it contains, so `mypy` allows both snippets. It could be a usable feature request - consider opening one [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues).

You can give this solution a try [in playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=ae6062b1147638334b21a1db602f1003).

And the last snippet above violates google style guide (`for` is longer than one line).